Parsing long URIs with .NET
Uri class implementation in .NET limits hostnames to a length of 255, which makes URL like scheme://1234...256 impossible to parse via Uri("scheme://1234...256") constructor, since it fails with a System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed exception. Is there a workaround that would allow me to use Uri class for non-RFC compliant URIs?

As if I wasn't aware of it. I specifically pointed that out, if you have nothing to add at least don't be toxic by downvoting the question

But it's not possible to have a web address of 1234...256? I typed it into my phone browser and it just googled for the phrase instead of treating it like a website. This question was the top hit btw; nice one :)

To be clear, the OP's mention of "non-RFC compliant" is in reference to RFC-1123 - Requirements for Internet Hosts -- Application and Support "Host software MUST handle host names of up to 63 characters and SHOULD handle host names of up to 255 characters."
